# Yahoo weather alert when it's raining

Tags: javascript, jquery, yahoo-weather-api

I'm trying to da when it's raining outside that I got "It's raining" on my page. But there is a problem. I allwys get "It's raining" evein when it's sunny. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <script>
        // Docs at http://simpleweatherjs.com
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $.simpleWeather({
            location: 'Grad Zagreb, Croatia',
            woeid: '',
            unit: 'c',
            success: function(weather) {
              html = '<h2><i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i> '+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
              html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
                  html += '<li class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</li>';
                  html += '<li>'+weather.wind.direction+' '+weather.wind.speed+' '+weather.units.speed+'</li></ul>';

                  $("#weather").html(html);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                  $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
                }
          });
          if(weather.code == 5 || weather.code == 6 || weather.code == 10 || weather.code == 35){
             $("#oprez").html('It's raining!');}


         });



        (function(e){"use strict";e.extend({simpleWeather:function(t){t=e.extend({location:"",woeid:"2357536",unit:"f",success:function(e){},error:function(e){}},t);var n=new Date;var r="//query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json&rnd="+n.getFullYear()+n.getMonth()+n.getDay()+n.getHours()+"&diagnostics=true&callback=?&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&q=";if(t.location!==""){r+='select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.placefinder where text="'+t.location+'" and gflags="R") and u="'+t.unit+'"'}else if(t.woeid!==""){r+="select * from weather.forecast where woeid="+t.woeid+' and u="'+t.unit+'"'}else{t.error("Could not retrieve weather due to an invalid location.");return false}e.getJSON(r,function(n){if(n!==null&&n.query.results!==null&&n.query.results.channel.description!=="Yahoo! Weather Error"){e.each(n.query.results,function(e,n){if(n.constructor.toString().indexOf("Array")!==-1){n=n[0]}var r=["N","NNE","NE","ENE","E","ESE","SE","SSE","S","SSW","SW","WSW","W","WNW","NW","NNW","N"];var i=r[Math.round(n.wind.direction/22.5)];if(n.item.condition.temp<80&&n.atmosphere.humidity<40){var s=-42.379+2.04901523*n.item.condition.temp+10.14333127*n.atmosphere.humidity-.22475541*n.item.condition.temp*n.atmosphere.humidity-6.83783*Math.pow(10,-3)*Math.pow(n.item.condition.temp,2)-5.481717*Math.pow(10,-2)*Math.pow(n.atmosphere.humidity,2)+1.22874*Math.pow(10,-3)*Math.pow(n.item.condition.temp,2)*n.atmosphere.humidity+8.5282*Math.pow(10,-4)*n.item.condition.temp*Math.pow(n.atmosphere.humidity,2)-1.99*Math.pow(10,-6)*Math.pow(n.item.condition.temp,2)*Math.pow(n.atmosphere.humidity,2)}else{var s=n.item.condition.temp}if(t.unit==="f"){var o="c";var u=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.condition.temp-32));var a=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[0].high-32));var f=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[0].low-32));var l=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[1].high-32));var c=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[1].low-32));var h=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[1].high-32));var p=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[1].low-32));var d=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[2].high-32));var v=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[2].low-32));var m=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[3].high-32));var g=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[3].low-32));var y=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[4].high-32));var b=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[4].low-32))}else{var o="f";var u=Math.round(9/5*n.item.condition.temp+32);var a=Math.round(9/5*n.item.forecast[0].high+32);var f=Math.round(9/5*n.item.forecast[0].low+32);var l=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[1].high+32));var c=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[1].low+32));var h=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[1].high+32));var p=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[1].low+32));var d=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[2].high+32));var v=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[2].low+32));var m=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[3].high+32));var g=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[3].low+32));var y=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[4].high+32));var b=Math.round(5/9*(n.item.forecast[4].low+32))}var w={title:n.item.title,temp:n.item.condition.temp,tempAlt:u,code:n.item.condition.code,todayCode:n.item.forecast[0].code,units:{temp:n.units.temperature,distance:n.units.distance,pressure:n.units.pressure,speed:n.units.speed,tempAlt:o},currently:n.item.condition.text,high:n.item.forecast[0].high,highAlt:a,low:n.item.forecast[0].low,lowAlt:f,forecast:n.item.forecast[0].text,wind:{chill:n.wind.chill,direction:i,speed:n.wind.speed},humidity:n.atmosphere.humidity,heatindex:s,pressure:n.atmosphere.pressure,rising:n.atmosphere.rising,visibility:n.atmosphere.visibility,sunrise:n.astronomy.sunrise,sunset:n.astronomy.sunset,description:n.item.description,thumbnail:"//l.yimg.com/a/i/us/nws/weather/gr/"+n.item.condition.code+"ds.png",image:"//l.yimg.com/a/i/us/nws/weather/gr/"+n.item.condition.code+"d.png",tomorrow:{high:n.item.forecast[1].high,highAlt:l,low:n.item.forecast[1].low,lowAlt:c,forecast:n.item.forecast[1].text,code:n.item.forecast[1].code,date:n.item.forecast[1].date,day:n.item.forecast[1].day,image:"//l.yimg.com/a/i/us/nws/weather/gr/"+n.item.forecast[1].code+"d.png"},forecast

        s:{one:{high:n.item.forecast[1].high,highAlt:h,low:n.item.forecast[1].low,lowAlt:p,forecast:n.item.forecast[1].text,code:n.item.forecast[1].code,date:n.item.forecast[1].date,day:n.item.forecast[1].day,image:"//l.yimg.com/a/i/us/nws/weather/gr/"+n.item.forecast[1].code+"d.png"},two:{high:n.item.forecast[2].high,highAlt:d,low:n.item.forecast[2].low,lowAlt:v,forecast:n.item.forecast[2].text,code:n.item.forecast[2].code,date:n.item.forecast[2].date,day:n.item.forecast[2].day,image:"//l.yimg.com/a/i/us/nws/weather/gr/"+n.item.forecast[2].code+"d.png"},three:{high:n.item.forecast[3].high,highAlt:m,low:n.item.forecast[3].low,lowAlt:g,forecast:n.item.forecast[3].text,code:n.item.forecast[3].code,date:n.item.forecast[3].date,day:n.item.forecast[3].day,image:"//l.yimg.com/a/i/us/nws/weather/gr/"+n.item.forecast[3].code+"d.png"},four:{high:n.item.forecast[4].high,highAlt:y,low:n.item.forecast[4].low,lowAlt:b,forecast:n.item.forecast[4].text,code:n.item.forecast[4].code,date:n.item.forecast[4].date,day:n.item.forecast[4].day,image:"//l.yimg.com/a/i/us/nws/weather/gr/"+n.item.forecast[4].code+"d.png"}},city:n.location.city,country:n.location.country,region:n.location.region,updated:n.item.pubDate,link:n.item.link};t.success(w)})}else{if(n.query.results===null){t.error("An invalid WOEID or location was provided.")}else{t.error("There was an error retrieving the latest weather information. Please try again.")}}});return this}})})(jQuery)


        </script>


        <div id="weather"></div>
        <div id="oprez"></div>

        </body>

        </html>
```

Need to add more text,texte,text,text,sorry for this

Comment: move that last IF into your success callback

Comment: Another problem you will face is the TTL of the feed which is one hour.. just sayin.

Comment: How can I make it shorter?

Comment: @dandavis Tnx that solved my problem

Comment: You can't - it's the terms for using their feeds (or more specific, they require you to cache the last result for TTL, which is 60 mins). You can always pull more often but that may get your IP banned/blocked for a period.

Comment: Hmm, that's not good. Is there some other service to do that without that rules?